# Test code inside an rxjs subscription when using jasmine marbles

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, rxjs, jasmine-marbles

I want to be able to test the code that runs inside an observable subscription:

```
function foo(someStream$: Observable<number>) {
  someStream$.pipe(
    map((x) => x + 3),
  ).subscribe((result) => {
    SomeService.someFunc(result)
  })
}
```

For example, I want to make sure `someFunc()` gets called with `result`. I would think that I should be able to do something like

```
const someStream$ = cold('-a--', { a: 5 })
const someFuncSpy = spyOn(SomeService, 'someFunc')
foo(someStream$)

expect(someFuncSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(8)
```

Problem is that I will be told that `someFunc` was never called. I do **not** want to separate the stream and the `subscribe` into separate functions.

Comment: what is `cold()` doing?

Comment: It lets me easily mock streams for testing: https://medium.com/@bencabanes/marble-testing-observable-introduction-1f5ad39231c

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Rx.Observable.of(5)` instead of `cold()` to pass a number through the observable